# Performance when using sequence of operations in a single line in cpp

Tags: c++

Recently I have started looking into C++ from the basics and got to know (to my surprise) that I can give series of expressions in a single line separated by commas in some cases as below

```
//it'll execute all the expressions mentioned after condition seperated by comma
for(int i=0;condition;++i,++x,cout<<"in for loop"<<endl,z = z*2);
(x>y)? ++z,z1 = z*2, cout<<"printing statement"<<endl:cout<<"condition failed"<<endl,z = z/2;
```

Here, I have a confusion after this is working. Is it safe to code in that way or is there any problem coding in such a way?

Please clarify!!!

***Correct me if i'm wrong anywhere, I'm just curious to know why most of the programmers don't use this way (I haven't seen such kind of lines anywhere)***

Comment: First concept of [tag:c++]: it is different then [tag:c]....

Comment: It's quite hard to read this kind of code, imagine going through a +500 line file where all lines are in this format.

Comment: BTW the answer is: 'cause they what to easily read their code after 1 year.....

Comment: The only problem coding like that is confusing yourself and your peers.

Comment: You may see some code like this in obfuscated C competitions.

Comment: Will coding in such a way have an impact on performace? (excluding the part that it is a confusing way to write code)

Comment: The advice "one statement per line" is a mantra.

Comment: @saikiran no. --

Comment: Imagine also debugging such code and trying to step "line by line"

Comment: You can leave all of the vowels  out of a book and still read it.  Why don't more authors do that?

Comment: Note that when you are distributing your source across a network *for automated use* (e.g. as part of a web page), you might want to write a code-size reducing tool. Humans are expected to only look at the *input* code.

Comment: If I could know why my query has been downvoted, I'll atleast know where I have gone wrong or how I should ask 1 atleast for the next time...

Answer (score 3):

The comma operator `,` evaluates each of its operands in sequence.  In standardese, there is a **sequence point** between the evaluation of the left operand and the right operand.

In a expression which contains a comma operator, the value of the left operand is discarded and the expression takes on the value of the right operand.  In both of the examples above, the comma operator is used in a `void` context, so none of the values are used.

So a statement like this where the value of the comma operator is not used:

```
exp1, exp2, exp3, exp4;
```

Is equivalent to the following sequence of statements:

```
exp1; exp2; exp3; exp4;
```

The first example is equivalent to the following:

```
for(int i=0;condition;) {
    ++i;
    ++x;
    cout<<"in for loop"<<endl;
    z = z*2;
}
```

And the second example:

```
if (x>y) {
    ++z;
    z1 = z*2;
    cout<<"printing statement"<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"condition failed"<<endl;
    z = z/2;
}
```

Note that this is considerably more readable that the one-line versions.  It's also easier to debug.  Since debuggers typically step through code a line at a time, it breaks up the flow and is more granular.

Comment: Possibly some extra verbiage on "sequence of sub-expressions whose values are discarded" == "sequence of statements formed of those sub-expressions + `;`"

Answer (score 0):

Not indenting and spacing your code *is not less costly regarding performance*. It is **unreadable**, **confusing** and **a pain to understand** for you and for anyone who'd have to work with it.
Lot of people will prefer *a well-syntaxed, beautifully and efficiently-indented code than a top-performance one*. You can modify, debug and refract a code which might not work but has the advantage to be understandable.
On the other hand, very few codes remain unchanged and stay unread. **There will always be a time when someone, may be you, will have to read it again** and if it looks like the one if your OP, it will be very time costly to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed. In my opinion and i say without a reference that in general other programmers do not find your 'for' loop very readable. Sometimes in a for loop you want to do other things then just `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){"do something"}`For example increment 'i' in every loop with two. Reading code should be like reading a text. If you are reading a book you do not want it to be unnecessary difficult.

Your other question was about the safety of the statement. The biggest problem with the code is that you  might get confused about what you are doing exactly. Bugs are caused by human errors (computers are deterministic and are executing machine code which ultimately has been written by a human) and the question about safety mainly depends on how you define it.

To give you some tips. When i just started programming C++ i looked a lot on CPP reference. I will give you a link where you can read about the syntax and what is allowed/possible. On this website there are quite a lot of examples on all kinds of statements. They will in general not put 5 or 6 operations within in a single line. If there are more variables that you want to change then you might want to do that in the scope of the for loop so it will be more readable instead of inside the for loop.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for